# "Node" commands not recognized, repairing Node installation is only a temporary fix

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-11

My rudimentary computer science knowledge is cobbled together from various Google and Stack Overflow search results over time, so if there is any missing information needed to help identify what is creating my issue, please let me know!

**CONTEXT AROUND PROBLEM:**

For the past two months, I've been following a tutorial to build an API and application using Node, Express, and MongoDB. Almost daily I've been executing `npm run start` in my terminal so that I can test my code with Postman and then eventually in my browser.  Until two weeks ago, I had no issues with executing node commands.

Now, I'm running into a weird issue where sometimes my PC seems to suddenly 'forget' where to find Node and I need to repair the Node installation to fix the issue. The dates when this has happened thus far are **September 26, October 3, & October 7** per my download history of the Node Setup Wizard, all with Node v18.18.0.

The *only* thing I can think of is that perhaps it has something to do with the way in which I install new NPM packages, but I have previously installed many npm packages without having any issues. My Windows profile is the only profile on my personal PC, so there are not any issues related to a 'systems administrator' or anything.

**HOW THE PROBLEM HAPPENS:**

- In the morning I turn on my PC and open VS Code.
- After making some changes to my code and saving them, I enter `npm run start` in my VS Code terminal that uses PowerShell (*not* "Windows PowerShell").
  **Error message**: `'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
- When I then open the PowerShell application, I try to enter `node -v`.
  **Error message:** `node: The term 'node' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`
- To confirm that this isn't limited to PowerShell, I have even opened the Windows Command Prompt application. Attempting to execute `node -v` in that application results in **Error message:** `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Thus, I've identified that the issue is not limited to the VS Code terminal, does not appear to be an issue with PowerShell, and instead appears to be an issue related to my general PC environment. My understanding is that when this error happens, my PC doesn't recognize node/npm commands because it no longer can access the destination of the node `.cmd` file(s) that tells my PC how to respond to node/npm commands.

**ENVIRONMENT:**

OS: Windows 11, Version 22H2
VS Code: v1.83.0
Node.js: VS Code says v18.15.0, since at least 9/26 it has been v18.18.0
Terminal: PowerShell v7.3.7 (**not** the OS' default "Windows PowerShell")

**ATTEMPTS TO SOLVE PROBLEM:**

1. **Checked my NODE_PATH**

   My PATH seems to be all good. Below are what seem to be the relevant entries:

   - Environmental Variables > User variables for (profile) > Path:

     - `C:\Users\(profile)\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin`
     - `C:\Users\(profile)\AppData\Roaming\npm`
   - Environmental Variables > System variables > Path:

     - `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`
2. **Check program files in File Explorer**

   Honestly, I don't know if any of the below information is useful, but here are the files I have for each path location referenced above:

   - `C:\Users\(profile)\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` files are `code`, `code.cmd`, and `code-tunnel.exe`
   - `C:\Users\(profile)\AppData\Roaming\npm` files are: `node_modules` folder, a few gatsby files, `ndb`, `ndb.cmd`, `ndb.ps1`, `nodemon`, `nodemon.cmd`, `nodemon.ps1`. (Nodemon being a tool for Node.js development.)

   For System variables path `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`, its folder contains:

   - `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` folder contains: `node_modules` folder, `corepack`, `corepack.cmd`, `installtools.bat`*,* `node-etw-provider.man` (typed here with dashes instead of underscores because of markdown), `nodevars.bat`, `npm`, `npm.cmd`, `npx`, `npx.cmd`

     - (I assume that only `npm` and `npm.cmd` are relevant, but I'm not fully sure!)

   My computer has `.cmd` files in each location, so I want to guess that the issue is not with missing files, but that contradicts my limited understanding of the error messages I receive.
3. **Repairing Node.js**

   - This fixes the issue, but only on a temporary basis. I go to [nodejs.org/en/download](http://nodejs.org/en/download) and download whatever the long-term-support file is for Windows (x64). On all three dates, that has been version 18.18.0.

     - It seems that v18.18.0 became the LTS version on September 18th. I'm not sure if I was on LTS version 14 (February 2023) or 16 (August 2023) when I had my first issue arise on September 26th. I did not install/repair my node installation between the release of LTS v18.18.0 and the 26th, so my issue would not be specifically related to that newest LTS version.
   - When the Setup Wizard opens, I click "Next" to start using the Wizard. Then I click on the **"Repair"** option to "[fix] missing and corrupt files, shortcuts, and registry entries". Finally, I click "Repair" on the next screen to execute it.
   - After I close out the Wizard by clicking on "Finish", I don't even need to restart my VS Code window - I can just re-execute `npm run start` in the still-open-from-earlier-window and then it executes as I expect it to.

**INSTALLING NPM PACKAGES:**

This is included in case *how* I install NPM packages is all of a sudden causing the issue. To note, whenever I install a package, that same day I am then able to continue executing commands such as `npm run start` or `npm run build`, so if this is the culprit it would be triggered after I close out of VS Code.

Below are ways that I install packages.

- `npm i -S [package-name]`
- `npm install --save [package-name]`

I'm not clear on the difference between `-S` and `--save`, because *either way* I will get an ESLint error afterwards that says that I need to run `npm i -S [package-name]` to list the package as a dependency on my project. Which is why I kind of alternate between the two ways of writing the command.

Comment: Seems clearly a system path issue.  So, you have confirmed that the 'Path' variable in the Environment Variables, system area includes the path to nodejs.
Also, can you provide the output of "Get-Command node" from the vscode terminal?

Comment: Also, can you ever run 'node' by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Malwarebytes as an anti-virus/malware protection tool, it has been falsely identifying node.exe as a threat for a few weeks and it removes the executable file (quarantines it).  This causes any tools that rely on finding it in your path to report that they can't find it (because it's been removed).

The latest version of Malwarebytes has fixed that false positive, so the fix for me was to simply check for updates and let it install the latest version.  This fix is present in Malwarebytes Premium 4.6.4.

I should repeat that there are no reports that there was ever anything wrong with node.exe, just that Malwarebytes was falsely detecting it as a risk.  That issue has now been fixed in Malwarebytes.

If you are running Malwarebytes, you can check your scan history and likely find that it detected this issue and removed node.exe.  That's exactly what happened to me.

Comment: I use MB and don't see the problem

Comment: @redwards - Perhaps it's platform-specific or has to do with your settings or version of node.exe installed? But, it's definitely a known problem on Windows 11 with MB v4.6.2 and it happened to me. There are discussions with MB support personnel talking about first a beta version that contained the fix and then the 4.6.4 version that released the fix.

Comment: Not doubting you.  I'm aware of the issue of the cmd.exe and node.exe flagging.  Was just curious why mine isn't flagged.  I don't usually actively use the Windows version.  Maybe that's it.

Comment: More to the point, this is indeed a plausible explanation to the problem.

Comment: @redwards - Yeah, I was completely baffled.  I got some notification from MB about node.exe, didn't understand exactly what the notification meant, then went to where I have node installed and saw that just node.exe was missing.  Looked into the MB notification more and saw that node.exe was quarantined by MB.  My first reaction was "oh sh....t" since I run several nodejs programs nightly.  Started wondering if my system was infected with something.

Comment: @redwards - Starting googling the issues and discovered many threads discussing a "false positive" from MB.  A temporary work-around while MB was working on a fix was to disable some of the MB settings or download a beta version where they were testing a fix, but fortunately for me, the update with the fix was already released by the time it hit me so I just needed to install the MB upgrade and then reinstall node.  No problems since.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Woah, that was exactly my issue! `nodejs\node.exe` and `node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js` were Quarantined on the specified dates where I had the issues. Thank you so much!